# Transiesta SCF not converged

Tags: density-functional-theory, siesta, graphene, quantum-dots, transport

I have encountered a convergence problem in my structure device in Transiesta calculation, the calculation doesn't converge. Recently I try to decrease the mixing weight parameter to 0.00001. For some small structures, it stops at 300 iterations without convergence. For big sizes strucutre (even with 0V), it tacks more than a month without convergence.
I would be grateful if can any one solve my problem with this error
any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Hello! Have you tried enlarging the electrodes and/or the scattering region?

Comment: Actually, I try with many sizes of the device width, and for some of them, the SCF doesn't converge. I couldn't change the electrode size, also the scattering (i take the size as some published examples).  Also, can we perform Transiesta with GPU in order to optimize the calculation time?

Comment: @Laura might not have seen your answer because you didn't use the @ character to ping Laura. Also, please do not ask new questions in comments, if you want to know about using GPUs to optimize the calculation time, please ask that in a separate post. Also, are you still urgently or actively in need of an answer to this question now that it's almost 1 year old? Laura was the answer to your comment enough for you to write an answer?

Comment: Indeed, I hadn't seen the reply to the comment, sorry. But without further info about the system, I would say to increase the size of the system or play with the parameters such as mixing weight etc.

Comment: Thanks @Laura. AH: perhaps you can provide further info about the system, or increase the system size or play with parameters as suggested by Laura.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transiesta with siesta version 4.1.5 not converging](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/11626/transiesta-with-siesta-version-4-1-5-not-converging)